# Why are, on a programming site, most basic programming principles always ignored?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask this question a long time ago.

There are some principles that are so basic to the degree of banality. Yet, for some reason, they almost never followed by Stack Overflow "community" (quoting because there is no actual community yet).

Some of these principles are

- Never trust user input
- Programmer should be attentive and pay attention to all the details
- Abstraction is a cornerstone of a programming.

What do we have on a blessed site of Stack Overflow?

- User input (i.e. Opening Poster's) is sacred. Whatever rubbish they say, no matter if it contradicts with error message provided or just common sense - Input is taken for granted. And then a half-dozen useless answers followed.
- Out of dozen OP problems only one is picked and proudly solved.
- Most funny part: for some reason the "community's" strongest belief is that **answer should be direct to the degree of dumbness.** This is indeed interesting phenomenon. **No context ever taken into account.** Question always taken literally. No research is ever done - no previous questions from the OP are checked, no problem is grasped at whole, no sanity check is performed. Why is that?  Why are sane answers so rare? **Why is every answer always taken as answerable?** Why is "community" so fierce against "meta-answers"? Here is one example:
  *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466398/trying-to-create-a-login-script-with-php-and-ends-up-stopped-at-processing-page*

Apart from the obvious "fix my code" off-topic post (of which nobody, nobody, nobody, nobody, nobody ever cares), there is a strange reaction from the crowd. They always want to kick the only sane answer - only because it is not "direct".

While any sane programmer would tell you that my answer there is most useful and practical. If you have complex code you can't make to run - split it up into simpler parts. What's so complex or incomprehensible or wrong in this answer? **What makes people think it "does not provide an answer"?!** Only its "non-directness"? **Come on, do we have programmers on this site at all?**

And - oh, that's it. It was just flagged, while I was writing this rant. Flagged by another ignorant policeman who have no idea of the question (most flaggers never bother even to *read the question*, let alone to *comprehend* it), and scarcely understands the answer.

What can we do to reduce the activity of such a vice? 
What can we do to direct its members attention to *questions* first? 
What can we do to educate these pinkertons in programming ways, to make them understand the context?

Comment: tl;dr you hate people who ask dumb questions.

Comment: Whoops. you missed context too. What a pity

Comment: Colonel, with all due respect I believe you're exaggerating the situation. Some of us do pay attention to contradictions in the questions, and will not answer a post containing more than one question (and will close it as too broad). You may have a point in your third bullet, though.

Comment: There are *lots* of counterexamples to the behaviour described here. For example, *most* of the time when I see a question where the code presented by the OP is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, this is mentioned in answers or comments. This rant is disproportionate to the degree of the problem, IMO.

Comment: (And there are plenty of questions with comments along the lines of "No, the code you've shown would not produce that error. Please edit your question to show actual code that demonstrates the problem.)

Comment: What makes me wonder is why it aren't closed yet ? What happened to the old good meta?

Comment: *no previous questions from the OP checked* dafuq.

Comment: @JonSkeet you too missed the point. The answer I am talking about is not a side note like one on the injection. A better example would be an answer that explains to the OP the debugging basics. Non-direct but the only helpful answer for many questions of "my code doesn't work" kind. The rant is actually on the problem called "SO people don't mind".

Comment: @Will that's just an *example* of the research action one can take while working on a question. Can change your understanding of the current OP's problem *drastically*. It's often worth doing.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Nah, bro.  Prefer OP to ask a good question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Well, I still don't think I missed the point - I just disagreed with it. You have to ask yourself whether if so many people are missing the point, there might not be one common factor: perhaps the rant just doesn't explain your point as well as you want it to, possibly *because* it's an over-the-top rant full of hyperbole?

Comment: @JonSkeet So, you disagreed with point which I failed to explain? Well, it happens too often on this site.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Although I am no fan of your mentality either (there are a lot more valid ways to learn programming than you seem to be aware of), I do think that your skill, dedication and mentality would be far more appreciated on codereview.SE than on SO, so that might be worth checking out. Over there "meta-answers" and answers that take an hour to write are sought after, as the question itself is open to any and all criticism unlike SO where 1 Q should be 1:1 with a single platonic answer (whether it actually gets written or not).

Comment: _no previous questions from the OP checked_ -- you seem to have forgotten that the Q&A are mostly for all the people who will read it AFTER the OP.

Answer (score 61):

While I do agree with some of your points, and I don't really see why it deserves all the downvotes you have now, there is a small issue that I feel needs to be addressed. So allow me to get side-tracked somewhat.

> It was just flagged, while I was writing this rant. Flagged by another ignorant policeman who have no idea of the question (most flaggers never bother even to read the question, let alone to comprehend it), and scarcely understands the answer.

I don't think you're flagged or downvoted because you are somehow fundamentally wrong. In fact, you are on many levels fundamentally right in many of the answers you give. You do however seem to lack a filter, or at the very least some form of self-reflection on how you might come across. A lot of what you write seems, for the casual observer, to fall between "angry" and "rant". Let's take for example the post you're referring to:

> > What am I doing wrong?
>
> Everything.
>
> But most essential fault is your attempt to sit on two chairs at once.
>   Learn either OOP or PDO at a time, but not both. And, as OOP require a
>   hundred times more efforts - better leave it alone for a while, a year
>   or two.
>
> Get rid of user class and try to authenticate user with raw procedural
>   PHP and PDO calls. For this task alone you have a long way to go.

Do you, on a very fundamental level, have a point? Maybe. You are however not addressing the immediate question. And you can be so much more constructive about the point you're trying to make.

Many of your answers to a question like *"I have problem Y, how can I solve that?"* are along the lines of *"You can't if you do stupid/outdated stuff like this. You seem to be lacking any level of fundamental skill. You need to get back to the basics and learn how to properly program or just quit. What you're doing now is just dangerous"*.

Aren't you exaggerating a bit there Bart? Yep, somewhat. But perhaps not so much regarding the effect it has on the casual observer, not to mention the OP. When subsequently another user steps in and states *"Ah, that's just a typo there. Throw some quotes around there and you're good to go"*, that really puts the nail in your coffin. *"If it's that simple to answer, why is this guy being such an ass?"*.

Let's make something clear; from my very minimal knowledge on the tags your participate in, and the various times I've come across your contributions to the various Metas, you don't just seem to be extremely knowledgeable and concerned with proper practice, but you also have a great concern for the community and site as a whole. So if it concerns you that much, why not adjust ever so slightly so you're listened to and that input you give is not dismissed as rude? Sure, thicker skin and all that, but fat chance of changing that.

If you were to simply address the question they ask, and then add information on proper practice, you'd achieve so much more.

Something along the lines of "The problem you report is fixed by adding some quotes. However, while that will work, it's not proper practice. If you really want to do it well, you should use X. It will take some time to grasp that, but you'll end up with far better and fundamentally safe code".

Then nobody can tell you that you didn't address the question. Nobody can tell you it's rude. You will have said what needed to be said, and there will be far less frustration all around.

Maybe worth a try?

Comment: This. Establish credibility by being polite, giving an answer to the immediate problem and *then* dispense the advice. The knowledge may be ignored by the poster, but years from now your advice might guide another novice programmer. Alternatively, don't answer at all. Some questions (while valid) add very little to the site.

Comment: If your police were addressing the tone, I wouldn't complain. They address the sanity of the answer. It drives me mad.

Comment: @TimMedora there is **no immediate answer can be given** for this question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Then why post an answer at all? It's not like you need the rep. Just comment, close-vote and move on.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen that's funny. As though I talked to noone. **Why you all take only immediate answer as answer?** Where did you get such a narrowed view? Who made it a habit? And, after all, **why should I follow your ridiculous idea on what an answer should be?**

Comment: Well why should _we_ follow _your_ ridiculous idea on what an answer should be? Because you say so?

Comment: @YourCommonSense - for an early user, it makes sense to put in the effort to fix someone's tone if they don't understand how they should behave and fit within the community.  When the user gets a significant enough amount of reputation, that tolerance goes away as it is expected that the user should not need babysitting anymore.

Comment: @Clive as long as you comprehend my answer - it's all right, I would respect whatever opinion based on understanding. The problem is that none of the volunteer policemen bother to dig on the problem.

Comment: @YourCommonSense why I don't get though is why you're not willing to move ever so slightly, if that would make the goal you seem to have (correctness and fundamental education) so much easier to reach. Perhaps it's annoying to have to adjust, but wouldn't it be far less frustrating if you then achieve that goal and won't have to deal with flags and the like any more?

Comment: @Bart I can tell you. That's really simple. I don't have a feeling that my contribution has any value. No matter which way you write your answer - it will go unnoticed. I can tell you *what* is frustrating: you spend a hour writing good correct answer and...  nothing. No response from the OP, no votes, no attention at all. Yes, you can show off for a while in a chat advertising your answer, promote it in a seemingly irrelevant meta post and get some profit out of it. Unfortunately I find this way disgusting. So, why bother at all? If the op got interested - they'd ask. I'll explain.

Comment: You have a point though, with your last comment. In fact, the situation is not that dire. I played a fool trying to combine long waiting question on programming basics and one particular trifle case that drove me mad. I took it as a sort of inspiration and it just overtook on me. But in general, if I see reasonable ignorance level around, I am quite calm and polite with my answers.

Comment: Maybe I'm far more positive about the potential of your contributions then @YourCommonSense. I see value in what you're trying to say, and potential in it being appreciated. I just think that the way in which you say it often harms both those points, and that's a shame.

Answer (score 44):

Your problem is that you're answering questions that just don't work in the SO format.

In this question, the user has asked for us to review his login code. It's riddled with easily visible problems, of which I've spotted some at first glance but probably not all. For the sake of completeness, let's list some of them:

- `stripslashes` calls either shouldn't be there or indicates that magic quotes is on. Either way it's a bad thing.
- `strip_tags` call isn't necessarily *wrong*, but we both just know upon seeing that that the author thinks that it magically protects him against all XSS attacks, and that now that his input is 'sanitized' he can echo it out in any context he feels like without needing any kind of escaping. A thorough answer that truly wanted to help him would have to explain XSS, santisation and escaping to him.
- Having passwords stored in a separate table to users when there's presumably a 1-to-1 relationship is a bizarre design choice.
- Using a single salt isn't a completely terrible thing to do, but means that if many users use the same password an attacker with access to the hashes can break many passwords for the cost of one. This, and why, would need to be explained in a thorough answer.
- We can see that on 'login', nothing is being set to a cookie or PHP session, nor is any kind of session token being stored in the database. Clearly this 'login' isn't going to persist once the connection terminates, which renders it kind of pointless.

The kicker is that even after spotting all of these fairly important problems, I still had *no idea* what was causing the vaguely-described problem that the OP actually asked about - that 'the page changes to process.php but nothing else'. So I wouldn't be able to point any of these things out in answer. And I haven't spotted everything, either; Jite's answer points out a simple bug I'd missed completely. And since the OP wasn't able to fix *that* one himself, I can see that our mythical thorough answer that addresses all the OP's problems would need to add into the mix teaching him how to check his error log, and the basics of debugging a program.

So what's my point?

Questions like this suck. They cannot be reasonably answered in the Stack Overflow format. The problems with the OP's code are so varied and pervasive that you would need to write fifty paragraphs to explain them all thoroughly, and what would be the point? It would require a massive investment of time and effort and never help anybody besides the OP. Doing such a thing is a waste of the time of anybody - like you - who is skilled enough to do it.

I know that you don't like the closure system - and there are lots of things I dislike about it too - but these questions simply need to be closed. Every fool who comes along, fixes a typo, and assures the OP that everything will be fine now is doing harm. They're giving false reassurance to the OP, giving the impression to future readers - if, gods forbid, there are any - that there's nothing horribly wrong with this code, and giving the impression to everybody who sees the question that it's okay to use Stack Overflow as your personal debugging service, rather than asking questions that will have value to future readers.

Posting an 'answer' that amounts to FUD and saying nasty things to the OP is... well, it's still arguably less harmful than posting an answer like Jite's that addresses only half the issues. But it's still just adding noise on top of noise, and not serving a purpose. As Bart points out, you'll be ignored by the OP anyway because most people would rather listen to somebody who is nice and supportive than to somebody who, in effect, tells them that they are an idiot and refuses to offer them the help that they want.

Downvote, closevote, and move on. Then focus your attention on creating thorough answers to broadly applicable questions that will help future users. You'll be more useful, and more importantly, you won't have to deal with the stress and discouragement that comes from answering bullshit.

The *real* problem here is not that your answer got downvoted - frankly, it doesn't answer the question, and it's questionable whether the advice it gives (like *'OOP require a hundred times more efforts'*) is good advice at all, so I don't blame the downvoters for the opinion they take on it. The real problem is that this terrible question has received a serious attempt at an answer (from Jite) and only received 2 close votes. Questions like this need to be burned on sight, not given legitimacy.

Comment: I agree, but I'd add that the only answer that stands any chance of being useful to the OP is the one Your Common Sense posted. He was just stating the truth. Of course the question should be closed. But this information is useful, maybe better posted as a comment, if the OP listens, it will help a lot.